# How to begin counting in ModelCheckpoint from an epoch greater than 1

Tags: python, keras

I am working on a project where Keras [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) is used. This callback class seems to cover my needs except for one small detail.

I have not found a way to pass a counter to the epoch numbering so as to deal with resume model training cases. I often train for some epochs and then resume training afterwards. I would like to have a consistent model saving pattern like:

```
model.{epoch:03d}-{loss:.2f}.hdf5
```

but with numbering beginning from the epoch the previous training stopped and not from the beginning.

The current command I use is this:

```
ckp_saver = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_dir + "/model.{epoch:03d}-{loss:.2f}.hdf5", monitor='loss', verbose=0,
                            save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)
```

Is there any way to pass this information to `ModelCheckpoint`? The solution I found is to edit the Keras code and add a default argument containing the actual pretrained epochs (defaulting in `0` if not passed) so as not to break any other code but I would prefer to avoid this if it's not necessary. Any other ideas?

The original code was taken from this file [here](https://github.com/omni-us/squeezedet-keras/blob/master/scripts/train.py#L246).

Comment: Does the `ckp_saver` command work?

Comment: Yeah it works fine. But the checkpoint counting starts each time from 1: 1, 2 etc

Comment: So on the first run everything is numbered correctly, but on the next run you want it to begin from the last checkpoint number plus 1?

Comment: Yeah that's correct